# Лексическая сочетаемость слова «причина»

Tags: лексическая-сочетаемость

**Это была единственная причина остаться.**
Подскажите, будьте добры, можно ли так сказать? Корректно ли использовать с инфинитивом слово "причина"?

Answer (score 2):

Я думаю, что так можно говорить.

В толковом словаре Кузнецова:
ПРИЧИ́НА -ы; *ж.*
**2.** Основание, повод, предлог для каких-либо действий, поступков.
*Смеяться без причины. Уважительная причина. **Нет причины быть недовольным.***

В толковом словаре Ушакова: ***Нет причины отказаться.***

Из книги ["Проспект активного словаря русского языка"](https://books.google.ee/books?id=LUFqAAAAQBAJ&pg=PA331&lpg=PA331&dq=%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0%20%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C&source=bl&ots=nnHEyryz_Y&sig=ACfU3U2YsMXcOjZ3FiSzSO5qLs-J5hxzhQ&hl=ru&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjtsvDpnYDkAhXJR5oKHQrICi4Q6AEwBXoECAgQAQ#v=onepage&q=%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0%20%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C&f=false) (коллектив авторов):
*У него была **причина обидеться и уйти**, но он решил этого не делать.

Ему не было **причины останавливаться** там, на болоте* (Б. Пастернак).

*Стало быть, у Клодия не было **причины ехать**, а была **причина остаться**, — у Милона же не было возможности оставаться, а была **причина**, и даже необходимость, **ехать*** (М. Т. Цицерон).

Answer (score 2):

Безусловно, так можно говорить.

(СЛОВАРЬ СОЧЕТАЕМОСТИ СЛОВ РУССКОГО ЯЗЫКА, ИНСТИТУТ РУССКОГО ЯЗЫКА им. А. С. ПУШКИНА, М., "Русский язык", 1983, с. 454)

Из словарной статьи ПРИЧИНА:

> *Причина для чего*: — для волнений, для радости, для беспокойства ...;
>   (**с неопр. ф.**) ~ *отказаться* от чего-л., *согласиться* с кем-чем-л,
>   *жаловаться* на кого- что-л. ...
>
> *У меня тысячи причин плакать, однако же я не плачу (Чехов).*

То есть, в Cловаре сочетаемости для контекста "причина для чего" вариант с инфинитивом рассматривается как модификация сочетания с отглагольным существительным. Но я бы посмотрел на это иначе: в сочетании с инфинитивом при том же контекте (**для чего**) можно увидеть сокращение от полной формы "**причина** [для того, чтобы] **остаться**". Полный вариант в большинстве случаев звучит излишне формально, поэтому гораздо шире используют краткий.